# How to reference <canvas> element from an angularjs directive?

Tags: angularjs, canvas, angularjs-directive

I am trying to make a directive to embed [planetaryjs](http://planetaryjs.com/)

I took the [basic example on the documentation page](http://planetaryjs.com/documentation/) and try to put it inside a directive:

```
angular.module('clearApp.directives', [])
    .directive('planetary', function () {
        var planet = planetaryjs.planet();
        planet.loadPlugin(planetaryjs.plugins.earth({
            topojson: { file: 'lib/json/world-110m.json' }
        }));
        planet.projection.scale(250).translate([250, 250]);
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                data: '='
            }, 
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var canvas = angular.element(element[0]);
                planet.draw(canvas);
            }
        }
});
```

and inside the html:

```
<canvas planetary width='500' height='500'></canvas>
```

It's not working. It's like `element[0]` is not referencing to the `<canvas>` element.

**here is the [code in plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/oEfLYV?p=preview).**

Do you know how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to load the module that contains the directive

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['clearApp.directives']);
```

Comment: oups, silly me… thanks for this. I updated the plunkr but it's still not working.

Comment: it is working. check the javascript console: angular.element:  
[canvas.ng-isolate-scope, ready: function, toString: function, eq: function, push: function, sort: function…]

Comment: sorry but I don't see it working :). I check the javascript console and i see an error: `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getContext'`and the planet is not displayed in the page…

Comment: the error is not related to angular since the directive is working. but since im in good mood i fixed the other errors aswell.
http://plnkr.co/edit/81Ikxaza38aXWyuCQYPu?p=preview